# Printable Invoice with CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to use html / css to build an printable invoice format:

What i'm trying to achieve
1. repeat the header on all page
2. have a text footer sticky to all pages

The problems :)
1.If the header is too big ( in height ) it will appear only one first page, I did a lot of research but I couldn't find anything about this. Did anyone manage to have it repeat on every page ?

2.The text footer is overlapping the invoice table. I tried to give padding to the .page container, to body to html, tried to change the margins of the page and put it outside, nothing worked.

Edit Mode
https://codepen.io/g_emanuel/pen/VQdeyX/

Debug Mode so can use CTRL+P https://s.codepen.io/g_emanuel/debug/VQdeyX/jVMpogGvQGyk

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <table class="invoice">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Invoice Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice body item</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
      </tfoot>
     </table>

    <div class="disclaymer">
        lorem lipsum
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your css

```
.disclaymer {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I put the padding for the head so i wont need to put all the content i have ( seller info, logo, buyer info, invoice details, payment details etc. ) With all the info i have i cant reduce it.

Comment: Changing the position from fixed to relative wont do nothing except of moving it to the last page. I need it on every page.

Comment: Then you can use Pagination to make the header, invoice body item and the disclaimer to be on the same page.

Comment: I don't want to use pagination and decide myself the number of items that fits the invoice. I prefer to have something automatic else if i have 2 products that will take 2 lines the page will break.